# Why function does not display what it is supposed to display?

Tags: r, display

I have the following code in R but I have problems in the output, it should display something different. This is what shows

```
Summary(x, y)

The total square sum is: 17.5The error square sum is: 0 
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "\n"

[[3]]
NULL
```

It was supposed to display

```
The total square sum is: number1

The error square sum is: number2
```

Could you please check it?

(This is somehow a sample, in reality I have to display more things `the standar error is: number3, the variance is number4, etc..`)

```
Summary <- function(x, y, print=TRUE) {
      p <- 2
      n <- length(x)

      x <- matrix(c(rep(1,n),x),n,p)
      bg <- solve(t(x)%*%x,t(x)%*%y)
      invx <- solve(t(x)%*%x)
      xty <- t(x)%*%y
      e <- y-x%*%bg
      SCT <- sum(y^2)-n*(mean(y)^2)
      SCE <- sum(e*e)

      result <- list(
        cat("The total square sum is:", SCT), 
        "\n", 
        cat("The error square sum is:", SCE, "\n"))
      return(result)      
}

x <- y <- 1:6
Summary(x, y)
```

Comment: What are the arguments you are passing to the function (x,y)?

Comment: @Chabo `x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)` and for `y` the same: `y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6) `

Comment: You can't "list" a "cat". `cat()` is a function that runs with side effects. It prints to the screen immediately. It returns NULL which is why you see that when the list gets printed.

Comment: @MrFlick oh I didn't know, I followed an example on another problem. How could I fix it then?

Comment: Well do you want your function to print something or return a value? If you just want it to print, then take out the `list()` part and just `cat()` the values, being sure to but the "\n" the `cat()` for a new line. you can `return(invisible())` so the function doesn't automatically print its return value.

Comment: What @MrFlick is suggesting: `A <- 1; B <- 2; cat("num A: ", A, "\n", "\n", "num B: ", B, "\n", sep="")`

Comment: ah it works now, thank you @MrFlick btw Why did you delete the other tags? This is about statistics.

Comment: @AkselA thanks, now it displays what should be displaying :)

Comment: MrFlick deleted those tags because while your code may be intended to deal with statistics, your _problem_ had nothing to do with those statistical concepts. For instance, no one struggling with performing a regression would find this question useful.

Comment: This question is really just about printing results to the screen. The fact that the code uses statistical functions is irrelevant. Tag spamming is not helpful to those following certain tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list()` creates a list from objects, but `cat()` does not return an object, it just prints to the console. That is why two of the list elements says `NULL` (they are empty, while one contains the character string `"\n"` (an actual object).

Printing text with more involved formatting can be difficult and non-intuitive, but I find that much inspiration and help can be found in existing R code.

Take `print.lm()` for example, which is the function responsible for displaying the result from linear regressions using `lm()`.

Run `stats:::print.lm` and you will see:

```
function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) 
{
    cat("\nCall:\n", paste(deparse(x$call), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), 
        "\n\n", sep = "")
    if (length(coef(x))) {
        cat("Coefficients:\n")
        print.default(format(coef(x), digits = digits), print.gap = 2L, 
            quote = FALSE)
    }
    else cat("No coefficients\n")
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
}
```

Looks a bit busy, but it's not too bad. You'll see that each call to `cat()` contains one or more character strings and delimiters (like `\n` and `\t` for new line and tabulate) laid out in order, with `sep`, the separator, specified at the end. Sometimes there is a `paste()` call inside `cat()`, in which case `paste()` merely 'prepares' some characters for `cat()` to print. We also note that there are several calls to `cat()` and `print()`, and mixing and matching is done, without issue. And at the very end is an example of `invisible()` as MrFlick mentioned in a comment. This command makes sure that the function won't print its argument (in this case `x`), but you can still assign it to a variable.

With these insights, can we improve on `Summary()`?

```
Summary  <-  function(x, y, print=TRUE) {
    p  <-  2
    n <- length(x)

    xm <- matrix(c(rep(1,n),x),n,p)
    bg <- solve(t(xm)%*%xm,t(xm)%*%y)
    invx <- solve(t(xm)%*%xm)
    xty <- t(xm)%*%y
    e <- y-xm%*%bg
    SCT <- sum(y^2)-n*(mean(y)^2)
    SCE <- sum(e*e)

    results <- list(TSS=SCT, ESS=SCE, p=p, x=x, y=y)

    if (SCE == 0) warning("Error square sum is zero", call.=FALSE)

    if (print) {
        cat("Results for the variables", "\n\t",
            deparse(match.call()$x), " and ", deparse(match.call()$y),
            "\n\n", sep="")
        cat("The total square sum is: ", SCT, "\n\n",
            "The error square sum is: ", SCE, "\n\n", sep="")
        invisible(results)
    } else {
        results
    }      
}
```

Looks a bit more involved. Lets test it.

```
Wendy <- Carlos <- 1:6

Summary(x=Wendy, y=Carlos)

Results for the variables
    Wendy and Carlos

The total square sum is: 17.5

The error square sum is: 0

Warning message:
Error square sum is zero
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer AkselA. I improved the code but in the output, in `the Result for the variables` part, displays `structure(c(1,1,...)) .Dim=c(6L,2L)` instead of Wendy name.

Comment: why does that occur?

Comment: @Isa: Notice that `x` is never reused as a variable name in my version of the function. When `x` is turned into a matrix I store it as `xm`, `x` remains as is. This is crucial for `substitute()` to work as intended.

Comment: How did you displayed both names then?

Comment: @Isa: I changed the function to use `match.call()$x` and `match.call()$y` instead of `substitute()`. Now it shouldn't be affected by variable reassignments.

Comment: :) aha now it shows the names. One more question why did you add to the code  `if (SCE == 0) warning("Error square sum is zero", call.=FALSE)` ? the warning

Comment: Just an example of another kind of message that can be returned. `SCE == 0` was chosen almost arbitrarily, an error of zero seemed to me like something potentially worth throwing a warning for. A statistical estimation with zero error usually indicates that something has gone wrong somewhere..